# How do I push to two different GitHub accounts using SSH keys in Powershell?

Tags: git, github

I'm on Windows 10 and I have Git for Windows installed.  I'm pushing code to two different GitHub accounts, and I'm trying to set up my SSH agent to use two keys (one for each account).

Here's my `~\.ssh\config`:

```
Host github.com-userone
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github.com-usertwo
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_usertwo
```

It works correctly if I push/pull using Git Bash, but I want to be able to use Powershell also.  When I try to do a push or pull from Powershell, I get the "please make sure you have the correct access rights" error.  If I run `start-ssh-agent.cmd` from Powershell, then `git push` works for that instance of Powershell.

If I add `start-ssh-agent.cmd` to my `profile.ps1` profile then the SSH agent starts and `git push` works correctly, but that seems to break other aspects of my Powershell profile (shown below).  The `Import-Module` and `Set-Theme` no longer work.  I don't get any errors; I just no longer get my posh-git or oh-my-git styling.

```
Import-Module oh-my-posh
Import-Module posh-git
Set-Theme Paradox
Set-Location "c:\users\brubin\documents\visual studio 2017\projects"
start-ssh-agent.cmd
```

Most of the instructions that I've found for getting this to work involve running `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`, however `eval` doesn't work in Powershell.

How do I set this up so that I can push/pull from two different GitHub accounts using Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need ssh-agent only if you have protected those private keys with a passphrase when creating them.

Second, make sure to use the right SSH URL form, referencing those ~/.ssh/config entries:

```
github.com-usertwo:<usertwo>/myRepo
```

As mentioned in [`dahlbyk/posh-git` issue 640](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/640#issuecomment-435515055)

> Rather than use Git's `start-ssh-agent.cmd`, I would use the built-in OpenSSH you have on Windows 10 1803.
>   To use this follow these steps:
>
> From a PowerShell window run `get-command ssh.exe`. You should see that `ssh.exe` is located at `C:\Windows\System\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`.
>   If you don't get any result, open Apps & Features section of the Windows 10 Settings app and press the "Manage optional features" link. Once that is open select OpenSSH Client to add that feature. After that has finished, open PowerShell again and see if `get-command ssh.exe` returns `C:\Windows\System\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`
>
> Now let's start the ssh-agent service and configure it to automatically start upon reboot.
>   Open PowerShell as administrator and execute:
>
> ```
> Get-Service ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic -PassThru | Start-Service
> ```
>
> Cd to your `$home\.ssh dir` and execute `ssh-add .\<private-key-file>` to add your private key file (and passphrase) to ssh-agent.
>   Last step is to get Git for Windows to use the WIndows native `ssh.exe`.
>   To do that, execute: `git config --global core.sshCommand C:/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe`.
>
> That's it! Now ssh-agent is running and serving your passphrase. It will continue to do so after a reboot (without having to re-enter your passphrase).
>   And even better, ssh-agent will work for apps (like Visual Studio) that you start from the Start menu instead of the PowerShell console - which you would have to do it you used `start-ssh-agent.cmd`.

Note:

> I typed "`Services`" in the `Start Menu` and I got a window listing all the services currently installed on the machine.
>   **I noticed that, next to "`OpenSSH Authentication Agent`", it said "`Stopped`".**
>
> I ran `Get-Service ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual -PassThru` and then `Start-Service ssh-agent` and it worked.
>   It seems like the service was disabled or something. I've never touched any of these things on Windows, maybe it comes as "Stopped" by default.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working by following your instructions, along with setting the remote URL for my second user's repository like `git remote set-url origin git@github.com-usertwo:usertwo/repo_name.git`

Comment: One question - now I'm getting `warning: agent returned different signature type ssh-rsa (expected rsa-sha-512)`.  It looks like there's a discussion about it on GitHub, but I don't understand enough about SSH to be clear on what they're talking about.  Is this anything to be concerned about?

Comment: @BenRubin Are you talking about https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1263? You could create a new key with `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -P` instead... (since the current ssh-agent packaged with Windows doesn't accept yet a typical rsa key)

Comment: Yeah, that's the one.  Does that error mean that my ssh agent isn't verifying the identity of the remote?

Comment: @BenRubin I think it does, since it is a warning. Test it with `ssh -Tv github.com-usertwo`